# Rendering a table from an array in react, best way to surround every five elements with a <tr>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a table in react from an array of objects, currently I'm mapping the array to this

```
            var objects = response.data;
            var arrayOfTableElements = []
            test.map(item =>
                testy.push(
                <td>
                    <a href = {item.title}>
                    <img src={item.img}/>
                    {item.title}
                    </a>
                </td>
            )
            );
            this.setState({data : arrayOfTableElements});
```

And I'm rendering like so

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="TopIMDBSeries">
           <table>
            <tbody>
                {this.state.data}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            );
     }
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to wrap every five td objects in a tr element? Right now my table elements are rendering buy they're all in a long row. Thanks guys.

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to save the rendered version of your data into state. Why not map at rendering time?

Comment: Sorry still pretty new to coding, but that makes sense I moved it to the render function. The issue remains however, I'm not sure how to enclose every five td elements in a tr?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in an array, I would say to do two loops and slice it up, something like this:

```
render() {
  const { test } = this.props; // assuming test comes from props
  return (
    <div className="TopIMDBSeries">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          { test.reduce((result, item) => 
            result[0].length < 5 && result[0] = result[0].concat(item) : result.concat([item]), [[]])
              .map(row => (
                <tr>
                  { row.map(item => <td>stuff you want inside</td>) }
                </tr>
              ))
            }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `reduce()` function basically groups each item into arrays with 5 items. Then, from that, do a `map()` which maps each row, wrapping the whole row in a `<tr>` then mapping each item to a `<td>` (I didn't copy everything you had for them, but that would go there).

As already mentioned, there is no reason to cache rendered components (and in fact, that should be avoided as it can have some nasty side effects).

If you wanted to cache the `reduce()` portion (but not the `map()` portion) to state, that could be appropriate, but probably unnecessary for almost every use case.